# Оповещения по емейл на локальном сервере

Tags: php, openserver

нужно сделать тестовое задание , в котором нужно осуществить  оповещения на емейл . Но как это сделать на локальном сервере ? Нужды в полноценном хостинге и домене нету , может есть какие-нибудь безплатные аналоги, чтобы просто протестировать  ?

Comment: Бегет дает бесплатный хостинг с PHP. Ну и есть множество хостингов с тестовым периодом. Почти все дают домен третьего уровня.

Comment: А в чем проблема с openserver? Там закладка "Почта", выбираете или складировать в локальную папку, или отправлять через удаленный SMTP сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот у меня есть локальный сайт, я использую Google SMTP для отправки писем, посмотри в сторону PHPMailer с использованием Google SMTP.

вот пример кода

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```